# Where do I find replacement parts for Agfa Billy Record cameras, from the 30s and 40s?

Tags: repair, old-cameras

I have an Agfa Billy Record 4.5 folding camera, which I believe to be from late 30s, and would like recommendations on the best online place to find replacement parts. Would anyone be able to help me?
Thank you very much for your attention!

Answer (score 2):

The two most common options are to shop online either for "New Old Stock" parts (often from gone-out-of-business repair shops) or for "parts-only" versions of the camera. I was fortunate to find some good sources for NOS bellows for Kodak folders, for example, but have had to scavenge other hardware from cameras that were beyond repair. I restored a like-new Kodak Model 3 from a $.66 body that had tattered bellows but was fine otherwise, a NOS bellows from a now-gone parts store, and a like-new in-kind shutter and lens from eBay. Set up a persistent eBay search for each part you need as well as for the whole camera and just be patient! The Agfa Billy Record has a great reputation and is worth restoring.